# How can I make `bquote` replace the greek letter stored in a variable with the symbol?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I want to label the axis on a plot dynamically. The labels come from a data frame and contain greek letters as well as super/sub scription.

In a static case, where I would know the letters of my labels, `bquote` would work well. But in the case, where the label-string comes from a variable, `bquote` fails.

This demonstrates what I want to achieve:

```
a <- "alpha"
b <- "beta"
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1), y=c(1)), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = bquote(.(a)[.(b)])) + ## will output the greek letters by "name"
  labs(y = bquote(alpha[beta]))  ## the greek letter-names are replaces by the symbols
```

[image: bqu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the a and b variable into symbols with `rlang::sym`.

```r
library("tidyverse")

a <- "alpha"
b <- "beta"

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1), y = c(1)), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = bquote(.(sym(a))[.(sym(b))])) +
  labs(y = bquote(alpha[beta]))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solved the problem in the question. I discovered however, that it actually i not my only problem. Maybe you are interested in my follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58689515/bquote-is-not-interpreting-the-styling-elements-within-a-variable