# `bquote` is not interpreting the styling elements within a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58685422/how-can-i-make-bquote-replace-the-greek-letter-stored-in-a-variable-with-the-s/58685698#58685698), only to discover that it is actually not quite my problem.

The problem seems to be, that I need the variable `ab` and `hello` interpreted by `bquote`, but it doesn't work. How can I make `bquote` to interprete the variable content?

```
a <- "alpha"
b <- "beta"
ab <- "alpha[beta]"
hello <- "hello[hello]"
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1), y=c(1)), aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = bquote(.(sym(a))[.(sym(b))]~.(sym(ab))~.(hello))) + ## will output the greek letters by "name"
  labs(y = bquote(alpha[beta]~hello[hello]))  ## the greek letter-names are replaces by the symbols
```

[image]

Edit:

With dipetkov's answer I did the following to define my label, which can then be simply used in ggplot's `labs` function. Note that the whole thing is wrapped in `bquote` while the the variable which needs styling is additional wrapped in `.(parse_expr(paste(...))`.

```
  ylab <- bquote(.(data$y_name[1])
                 ~.(parse_expr(paste(f(data$y_symbol[1]))))
                 ~"="~
                   "["*
                   .(data$y_unit[1])
                 *"]")
ggplot(...) + ... +
labs(y = ylab)
```

Edit 2: actually, the `paste` is unnecessary in my case.

[image]

Comment: What labels do you expect in X and Y-axis ? What is your expected output ?

Comment: What is shown on the y axis. I want that bquote styles the variable content instead of taking it as a simple string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there... The tilde symbol, `~`, doesn't print with either `bquote` or `parse_expr` (because in R it signifies a formula?). So I've substituted it with a dash, `-`.

```r
library("rlang")
library("tidyverse")

ab <- "alpha[beta]"
hello <- "hello[hello]"

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1), y = c(1)), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = parse_expr(paste(ab, "-", hello))) +
  labs(y = bquote(alpha[beta] ~ hello[hello]))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>